# Match exact word with awk on Mac OS X

Tags: regex, macos, bash, awk

Try to use awk on Mac OS X. One example:

```
$ echo "abc stock def" | awk /stock/ 
abc stock def
$ echo "abc stockholder def" | awk /stock/
abc stockholder def
```

I got trouble when I try to exact match a word with awk. For instance, I want to match `stock`only instead of `stockholder` in above example. I tried with `\<`, `\>`, `\b`, `\y`. However all of them did not give me expected results.

Thanks

Comment: Why with `awk`? `| grep -w "stock"` makes it.

Comment: I knew I can grep. However, I need to use awk to process a file across all lines. Regex match is just the first step. Thanks

Comment: If you want to match just stock then just leave a space before and after stock  
    `echo "abc stock def" | awk / stock /`

now it will only match stock as a complete word.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Jidder. However, consider the case, that "stock" is the last word in the line with no space? That is the reason for matching "the end of a word".

Comment: @Lszomb does it matter the position of the word in your string? Because if it is the 2nd, then this makes it: `awk '$2 == "stock"'`.

Comment: @fedorqui: nope, the word can appear anywhere in the a string. I need to find the exact string of "stock" from a string.

Comment: `\<` etc are GNU awk only constructs. gawk isn't the default awk on OS X.

Answer (score 4):

You can use regex like this:

```
$> echo "abc stock def" | awk '/(^| )stock( |$)/'
abc stock def

$> echo "abc restock def" | awk '/(^| )stock( |$)/'
$>
```

**Update:** For matching more boundaries other than space or start/end anchors use this regex:

```
$> echo "abc-stock-def" | awk '/[^[:alnum:]]stock[^[:alnum:]]/'
abc-stock-def

$> echo "abc-stocks-def" | awk '/[^[:alnum:]]stock[^[:alnum:]]/'
$>
```

I have also installed `gnu-awk` via `homebrew` on my Mac and using which I can do:

```
echo "abc stock def" | gawk '/\<stock\>/'
abc stock def

$> echo "abc restock def" | gawk '/\<stock\>/'
$>
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is always in the 2nd position, you can use:

```
awk '$2 == "stock"'
```

If it can be in any position, then use:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == "stock") {print; next}}'
```

See example:

```
$ echo "abc stock stock def" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == "stock") {print; next}}'
abc stock stock def

$ echo "abc stockd def" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == "stock") {print; next}}'
$
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Program wise and technically, this is perfect. However, I keen to know more about why both BSD and GNU version of regex match did not work for awk on Mac OSX. I will accept your answer if no-one else give a regex version.

Comment: Well I think you don't need any regex if the comparison is with a fixed string.

Answer (score 1):

A typical definition of a word-consituent-character (e.g. `\w` for GNU awk) is any alpha-numeric or underscore, so:

```
$ cat file
abc stock def
abc stock. def
abc stockholder def
abc stock
stock def

$ awk '/(^|[^[:alnum:]_])stock([^[:alnum:]_]|$)/' file
abc stock def
abc stock. def
abc stock
stock def
```

Change `[:alnum:]_` to whatever your definition is if not that.

Comment: [POSIX](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) defines `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` as word boundary. I tried it on my mac but got no output. I forced `--posix` option ended up with same results. Does `awk` uses it's own regular expressions?

Comment: I've never heard of those character classes and frankly I don't believe it, I think the web site you're referring to is wrong but I'm open to correction. Can anyone point us to the POSIX spec that defines this?

Comment: @jaypal: Actually `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` work fine with sed on OSX but strangely awk doesn't support them.

Comment: I've no doubt the constructs exist and work in some tools, I just don't believe they're POSIX. The site that states they are POSIX has some other issues and seems to be trying to describe all possible constructs that can appear in REs in all tools which is nice but it doesn't do a great job of identifying which constructs go with which tool or standard.

Comment: I found the most recent (2013) POSIX character classes posted at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html and there's no mention of `[[:<:]]`.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use below approach (also works for languages without regex support):

```
echo " abc stock def " | grep ' stock '
echo " stock abc def " | grep ' stock '
echo " abc def stock " | grep ' stock '
```

Note the spaces at the start & end of the input & pattern.
Here, the parser (`grep` in this example) does not need regex support. Even `C`'s standard function [strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) can also match this...